# mysqli prepared SELECT query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP mysqli prepared SELECT statement but it is not working. here are some details you would need to know.

The table name is 'userbalance'. There are 2 columns, ID and balance.

At the moment, I have only 1 row in the table, where ID=76561198061537594 and balance=10

ID is a bigint and balance is a decimal.

Here is my code:

```
require ('steamauth.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {  }
else {
    include ('userInfo.php');
}

include("conninfo.php");
$userid = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM userbalance WHERE ID = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $credits);
$stmt->close();
echo "Credits: $credits";
```

If I echo `$userid`, I get `76561198061537594` which is the correct ID.

But the output is shown as `Credits:`. The `10` of the balance doesn't show.

Whereas, If i replace `WHERE ID = ?` with `WHERE ID = 76561198061537594` it works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please **edit the question** and post the exact code you use to print `$id`? (You'd be surprised to know how many issues like this are due to a simple spell error.)

Comment: I don't really need that. Before I was just using "SELECT balance FROM userbalance WHERE ID=?" but since that didn't work I put in the asterik. It doesn't help anyway. I am not printing $id anywhere

Comment: Question is why 10 doesn't show. You don't have code to show 10. You say you don't really need it. Problem solved then?

Comment: wow.. man the question is, $credits doesnt show.. I have the command echo "Credits: $credits" but, no value is coming out for $credits. the query fails to fetch results

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared statement is working, but you never fetch the results. If you are using result binding, you need to use `fetch()` method to assign value to your result variables.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID, balance FROM userbalance WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $credits);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "Credits: $credits";
```

One more advice: you should specify your columns explicitely in your `SELECT ID, balance` instead of `SELECT *`.

Answer (score -2):

Since `$userid` is integer, you're using the wrong [type](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) ('s' corresponds to string); try this instead:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
```

Comment: doesnt't help. plus i read somewhere it's better to use 's' with bigints